# Check function exists in C langauge by base script program

Tags: c, bash

I want to know how to check function exist in C language program by bash script programming.

Suppose I made a program in C language:

**fun.c**

```
void add();
void main() {
  add();
}
void add() {
  printf"hello");
}
```

I want to check by bash script that above program function exist or not?

```
#!bin/bash ? ? ? ?
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get the point. If you define the `add()` function, then it exists...

Comment: What is the point of that? Do you want to search if any C file from whatever project it might come implements an `add` function?  That is not a reliable way to find proper implementation.

Comment: Your problem description is vague. Are you looking for a specific function definition, or declaration, in a C source file?

Comment: I agree this requires editing, For now, in bash try grep -nx 'void add()' *.c or to safeguard multiple spaces use regex  like grep -n 'void\s+add\(\)' *.c

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience to understand my question. Actually i am asking  this question because i am using Moodle platform in my lab. And i want that when i submit question to student. They only make program by function. if they do then automaticaly  moddle  set grade  to  student. but it might be possibility that they will make program without function. and moodle only check answer. answer could come in any way using function or without function. so i want to do program which check function available in program or not. And in moodle i can do programming only in bash .

Comment: In that case, both existing answers are more or less invalid/incomplete, and i will delete mine. You need a different approach, because i suspect that you don't just care about the existence of the function, but also if it returns the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp file and add a line in which the function is used whose existence is to be checked:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cp func.c /tmp/func.c                            # Create temp file
echo "void testAdd() { add(); }" >> /tmp/func.c  # Append test line
gcc /tmp/func.c -o /dev/null                     # Run test

if [ $? -eq 0 ]                                  # Check gcc's exit code
then
  echo "function add() exists"
else
  echo "Can't find add() or other error"
fi
```

Using `-o /dev/null` gcc's output is discarded. When the function exists and there are no other errors, gcc should pass. Otherwise an error message should be returned and exit code `$?` is not zero:

```html
func.c:10:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘add’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 void testAdd() { add(); }
```

However, the function signature must always be known, otherwise an error will occur:

```html
func.c:10:18: error: too few arguments to function ‘add’
 void testAdd() { add(); }
```

If the test should not depend on the function signature, this test line can be used instead:

```c
void testAdd() { void* a = add; }
```

However, add could also be a global variable instead of a function here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I am very grateful to you. Can we check function exist or not in program if we don know what function  declared in the program.

Comment: "don't know what function" means the name of the function, its return type or its parameters?

Comment: I am desperately waiting for a solution if we don't know what the name of the function and return type or its parameters  use student.